# Edittext error message is shown incorrect

Tags: android

Tested on htc one v android 4.0.3

**Activity:**

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.setError("Error msg");
        }

    }
```

**Xml:**

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**Steps:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Expected behavior: error message is shown in correct position. Anyone knows how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Here is your Error show code . xml not have it, Poat your java code.

Comment: try add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity in manifest file

Comment: adjustResize works, but it does not suits me because this option resizes layout

Comment: `<EditText ... android:layout_height="wrap_content"` try `match_parent` (the button may become invisible). If the problem disappears, use a RelativeLayout instead of the linear one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
try this:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

/*
Instantiate and pass a callback
*/
SoftKeyboard softKeyboard;
softKeyboard = new SoftKeyboard(mainLayout, im);
softKeyboard.setSoftKeyboardCallback(new SoftKeyboard.SoftKeyboardChanged() {

@Override
    public void onSoftKeyboardHide() 
{
        // Here request your errorMessage
    }
@Override
    public void onSoftKeyboardShow() 
{
        // Here request your errorMessage
    }   
});
```